# Creating a file named '.' and how to read and write data to it?

Tags: directory, filenames, directory-structure

How would I create a file named `.` (dot) and read or write data to it, given that `.` also refers to the current directory?

I know this is possible because I have a directory structure. I'm looking at with `ls --all -l` that shows a file named `.` owned by a different user than the user that owns the `.` and `..` directories.

Comment: Not possible, but you can create a file that appears as just "." to `ls` output. For example: `touch ". "`. You won't be able to tell the trailing space is there in `ls` output.

Comment: Also, I would be very suspicious of a file named `". "`, as dir names such as that is often used to hide malicious code.

Comment: i don't want to execute it, just to find what's in it. It seems you are probably right that the file isn't actually named '.' but i can't figure out how to cat it. i basically want to escape the . and say something like .* i guess, but it's not working

Comment: What do you get with `printf '%s\n' .* | sed -n l` ?

Comment: 3 lines: (.$\n
.\\ \\ $\n
..$\n). \n denotes a newline in the output

Comment: thanks. Found what was in it. Had 2 spaces instead of one in front of the .

Comment: Then the file seems to be named `<dot><space><space>`. Change its name with `mv .\ \  newname` if you could. If not check first which type of file it is with `file .\ \ ` and (if it is a text file), view it with `less .\ \ `

Comment: @Isaac spaces do not need to be escaped inside of single quotes. A \ inside of single quotes is a literal \.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid it only looks like you have a file called `.`. What is very likely happening is that you have a file whose name starts with a dot but is then followed by a whitespace or other special character. To demonstrate how you'd figure this out:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ touch '. '
$ for path in .*
> do
>     printf '%s' "$path" | xxd
> done
00000000: 2e                                       .
00000000: 2e20                                     . 
00000000: 2e2e                                     ..
```

The dotfile (the second entry above) shows up as a dot (0x2e) followed by a space character (0x20).

Comment: Note that `%q` is not POSIX. Yes, it works in bash, (*)ksh, zsh (with similar but not identical results) but not in older POSIX shells.